# Get a Config Message every day but won't install

Tags: settings, apn

Every day I get a Configuration Message
Application: Access Point Name
Name: MMS
APN:unet
User name: 
etc.

When I chose "Full Install" it asks for the PIN 
If I enter the wrong PIN it asks again for the PIN
If I enter the right PIN (0123) I get an error report
"INSTALLATION REPORT
Access Point Name: Failed"

I believe this has something to do when I added a new SIM which has since been removed.